# My app Nodejs passport local authentication is keep on loading

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I am creating an app with node js (express and mongodb), trying to do authentication with passport local. when i click on log in, everything running fine but after comparing credentials success redirect not working (keep loading). but if credentials not matched then failure redirect is working fine without any error.

## **what is wrong? where? can anyone help to find out? please...**

my login route ->

```
router.post('/createSession',
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/users/SignIn', failureMessage: true }),
  usersController.createSession);   //createSession is controller defined in usersControllers
```

passport local_Strategy config->

```
const passport=require("passport")
const LocalStrategy=require("passport-local").Strategy
const User=require("../models/user")

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField:"email"
    },
    function(email,password,done){
        User.findOne({email:email},function(error,user){
            if(error){
                console.log("error in finding passport");
                return done(error);
            }
            if(!user || user.password != password){
                console.log("User not found passport_local_stra");
                return done(null,false)
            }
            return (null ,user);
        })
    }
))
passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
    return done(null,user.id);
})
passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
    User.findById(id,function(error,user){
        if(error){
            console.log("Error in finding user at deseriali..");
            return done(error);
        }
        return done(null,user);
    })
})
```

Comment: What does `return (null ,user);` mean? Shouldn't it be `return done(null ,user);`?

Comment: @anatoly ,oh my bad i missed that ,thanks it works after correction.